# Load-time weaving for Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, aspectj

In AspectJ there is load-time weaving, is there a similar concept using Quarkus?

I'm trying to add/apply an Quarkus interceptor without modifying the original source code (i.e., without adding annotations)

```
project P
    module M
        main 
            interface I {
                void myMethod()
            }
            class C implements I {
                void myMethod() {...}
            }
        test 
            new C().myMethod()
```

I want to execute code (to generate metrics) when any myMethod is called during test execution, but without directly modifying the Java code of X.
If I could modify the Java code in X, I'd just add an Quarkus Interceptor to myMethod, so I'm looking for an AspectJ-like way (i.e., load-time weaving) of doing this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to intercept? Is it just one specializec method? I can maybe sorta kinda imagine something, involving writing an extension, doing some byte code replacement (which is possible through extensions), but I am a) not entirely sure if this would work and b) if it does, how it would perform. Plus, we'd have to replace each method we want to intercept.

Comment: You don't need to modify bytecode just to be able to add an interceptor binding annotation to a method. The CDI container in Quarkus, ArC, exposes a bunch of extension points, which are accessible through the Quarkus extension system. One of them is an annotation transformation facility -- see https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-integration#annotations_transformer_build_item

Comment: @Turing85 it's one method from an interface implemented in several classes. worse performance shouldn't be a problem in my case

Comment: I take it you can't add annotations and there are no annotations to start with? So basically you want to check each class as it is loaded and (when it uses your interface) apply the interceptor?

Comment: @ewramner I just added an example to my question

Comment: @Ladicek AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem looks promising, but how would i use it in my case (just added an example in the question part).

Comment: Well you'd need to write a Quarkus extension. You can start here: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions